# bootstrap Jquery datepicker issues

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the datepicker as such:

```
 $('#fromDate').datepicker({
                "changeMonth": true,
                "changeYear": true,
                "numberOfMonths": 2,
                "onClose": function(selectedDate) {
                    $('#toDate').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }

            });
            $('#toDate').datepicker({
                //"defaultDate": "+1w",
                "changeMonth": true,
                "changeYear": true,
                "numberOfMonths": 2,
                "onClose": function(selectedDate) {
                    $('#fromDate').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
```

I set the default date in C# codebind as such:

```
 var dt = DateTime.Now;
        toDate.Value = dt.ToShortDateString();
        fromDate.Value = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

this get displayed as :

[image]

However, when i click the calendar icon, it shows as the six month, third day, and anyother selection is in this format. i've tried this but no joy:

```
$(function() {
                $("#fromDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy" }).val();
                $("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy" }).val();
            });
```

How do i change it so that I have a format of dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: The option is `format`, not `dateFormat`.

Comment: nope, no change, still thinks its the sixth month

Comment: Are you using the jQuery datepicker or the Bootstrap datepicker? I was assuming Bootstrap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
   $("#from").datepicker({
        "changeMonth": true,
        "changeYear": true,
        "numberOfMonths": 2,
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",                   //whatever format you need.
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {

        }
```

Follow same for toDate

[JS FIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/X2BFT/5/)

Comment: please see the from date text box in fiddle demo.

Comment: the question is not how to use jQuery datepicker, bt why is it not working for him

Comment: See the question, How do i change it so that I have a format of dd/MM/yyyy? So I gave him this approach.

Comment: :) and the approach u gave him is already there in his question.

Comment: But I have given demo with his requirement working :)

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, this isn't working for me. What datepicker.js file are you using?